# trying to get 'Growth Rate' to google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, stock

for the following example i try to get Growth Rate for ticket in index C1:

=IMPORTXML(concatenate("https://www.gurufocus.com/term/dividend_growth_5y/",index(C1),"/5-Year-Dividend-Growth-Rate/"),"//*[@id="target_def_description"]/p[2]/strong[9]")

the data is in the following page:
[https://www.gurufocus.com/term/dividend_growth_5y/T/5-Year-Dividend-Growth-Rate/ATT-Inc#:~:text=AT%26T's%20Dividends%20per%20Share%20for,Rate%20was%201.80%25%20per%20year](https://www.gurufocus.com/term/dividend_growth_5y/T/5-Year-Dividend-Growth-Rate/ATT-Inc#:%7E:text=AT%26T%27s%20Dividends%20per%20Share%20for,Rate%20was%201.80%25%20per%20year).

please advice
10x
Y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I tested your formula using your URL, an error of `Could not fetch url` occurs. So in this answer, as a workaround, I would like to propose to use Google Apps Script for achieving your goal.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet, and put a custom formula of `=SAMPLE(url)` in a cell. By this, the script is run.

```
function SAMPLE(url) {
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {muteHttpExceptions: true});
  if (res.getResponseCode() != 200) throw new Error(res.getContentText());
  const meta = res.getContentText().match(/<meta name\="description"[\s\S\w]+?>/);
  if (meta) {
    const gr = meta[0].match(/ ([0-9.]+%)/);
    if (gr && gr.length == 2) {
      return gr[1];
    }
  }
  return "Value cannot be retrieved.";
}
```

#### Result:

When above script is run for the URL of `https://www.gurufocus.com/term/dividend_growth_5y/T/5-Year-Dividend-Growth-Rate/ATT-Inc#:%7E:text=AT%26T%27s%20Dividends%20per%20Share%20for,Rate%20was%201.80%25%20per%20year` and `https://www.gurufocus.com/term/dividend_growth_5y/T/5-Year-Dividend-Growth-Rate`, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### Note:

- This sample script can be used for your URLs of `https://www.gurufocus.com/term/dividend_growth_5y/T/5-Year-Dividend-Growth-Rate/ATT-Inc#:%7E:text=AT%26T%27s%20Dividends%20per%20Share%20for,Rate%20was%201.80%25%20per%20year` and `https://www.gurufocus.com/term/dividend_growth_5y/T/5-Year-Dividend-Growth-Rate`. So when you change the URL, the script might not be able to be used. So please be careful this.

#### References:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)
- [Class UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)